# Display settings to make images take up a whole line of a div

Tags: html, .net, css

I've got some CSS that looks like

```css
.drugCard
{
    width:280px;
    height:375px;
    border: 10px solid;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
.drugCard span
{
    display:block;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;
    font-size:xx-large;

}
.drugCard img
{
    padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

with output that looks like
[image]

You can see in the right picture were there are three pictures the date is present at the bottom of the pictures.  This is because those three pictures fill up the div completely.  What CSS do I need to make the date always appear on a new line?

These are .NET-generated controls so I would prefer a one-liner CSS if there is one vs. manually editing the HTML.  Currently the date you see is added as literal text to the page.
EDITED to add markup:

```html
<div class="drugCard" style="border-color:Chocolate;">
    <span>BISCOLAX</span><img src="Images/Nausea.jpg" style="height:75px;width:75px;" />11/19/2012 12:00:00 AM
</div><div class="drugCard" style="border-color:DarkOrange;">
    <span>RENAGEL</span><img src="Images/Pain.jpg" style="height:75px;width:75px;" /><img src="Images/Sleepiness.jpg" style="height:75px;width:75px;" /><img src="Images/UpsetStomach.jpg" style="height:75px;width:75px;" />11/9/2012 12:00:00 AM
</div><div class="drugCard" style="border-color:MediumAquamarine;">
    <span>VYVANSE</span><img src="Images/Sleepiness.jpg" style="height:75px;width:75px;" /><img src="Images/Fever.jpg" style="height:75px;width:75px;" /><img src="Images/Nausea.jpg" style="height:75px;width:75px;" />1/29/2013 12:00:00 AM
</div>
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: To make the date appear on another line you need to apply `clear: both;` in the css for the date

Comment: @Javalsu is that the easiest way to do this?  Currently the date you see is added as literal text, so I would have to add it to a div then add that div to the parent control as there's no way to add a class to literal text.

Comment: It's the proper way to do it.  the clear property tells the dom that this element can't have floating elements on either side.  Anything else you do would be kludge and unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a  around your date value and set its clear value to both in css.

HTML:

```
   <span class="date">11/9/2012 12:00:00 AM</span>
```

CSS:

```
.date{
    clear: both;
}
```

P.S.: As you have already set some of the properties of span when you used it for titles, you need to clear those properties for your time element OR use any other element instead of span.

Comment: I would say it doesn't really make sense to use a span here, a p tag or a h1-6 tag would make more sense semantically, or even a time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time tag. Generally I use span within other text elements to call out something special about that text, not as a general text container.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your markup looks like, you need to use [clear: both;](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/clear) on your date element.

Clear will push the cleared element below any floats that precede it in the markup.